# Implement Jmeter/taurus with Openshift

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, openshift, taurus

I am Implementing Jmeter/taurus for performance testing for microservices. We are using Openshift PaaS solution to run all microservices. I am able to deploy jmeter/taurus inside Openshift using jenkins pipeline and generated the taurus report using jmx report in the container. My requirement is to publish the taurus report to Jenkins, rather than storing it to cloud storage or nexus. Can someone advise me what should be best approach to publish performance report for developers on Jenkins or any other optimal way to publish.

I found something by googling where they Jenkins agent was deployed inside Openshift and checkout the test suite Git repo into the agent's workspace just want to make sure if this is the best approach for my scenario. Our Jenkins master is running on Google cloud platform VM's with some dynamic slaves.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

According to [Dump Summary for Jenkins Plugins](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Reporting/#Dump-Summary-for-Jenkins-Plugins) Taurus User Manual Chapter, you just need to add `reporting` module definition to your YAML configuration file like:

```
reporting:
- module: final-stats
  dump-xml: stats.xml
```

And "feed" this `stats.xml` file to [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/performance)

[image]

That's it, you should get `Performance Report` added to your build dashboard. Check out [How to Run Taurus with the Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-taurus-jenkins-performance-plugin) article for more information if needed.

Comment: I was able to produce stats.xml, but how can I take it onto the jenkins server since that resides inside the container? Above solution will work once the report is available on Jenkins server or one of the slave.

Comment: did you mean to run Jenkins slave in Openshift?